# Showing union of [0,1) and [2,3] with standard $R^{n}$ metric is not connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know a metric space X is connected if the only two subsets which are simultaneously open and closed are X and the empty set but I'm having trouble relating this definition to the question

Any help appreciated

Comment: You have to use the induced topology (subspace topology).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that $[0,1[$ is clopen in your space.

Comment: [2,3] is closed in X ⟹ [0,1) is open as it's the complement. But I'm not sure how to show it's closed. Thanks

Comment: The complement $[2,3]$ of $[0,1[$ is open because $[2,3] = X \cap ]1, 4[$ (recall that open sets in $X$ are intersections of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with $X$).

Answer (score 0):

$[0,1)$ is open in the subspace $X$ because it equals $B_d(0,1)=\{x \in X: |x| < 1\}$ where $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric (here restricted to $X$) or because its complement in $X$ is $[0,2]$ which is closed in $X$.
Or because we can wrte it as $(-1,1) \cap X$, the intersection of an open subset of $\Bbb R$  with $X$.

It's also closed in $X$ as $\{x \in X: d(x,y) \le 1\}$ or $[-1,1]\cap X$ via similar reasoning.

So $[0,1)$ (and also its complement $[0,2]$) is both closed and open in $X$.